# Transforming from one to many with Guava

Tags: java, collections, transform, guava

I have situation where I want to extract multiple values from multiple source objects into a collection. I tried to achieve this with Guava's transform, but ran into the problem that I get back a collection of collections which I have to 'flatten' manually. Is there a nice way to get the results back directly in a flat collection?

```
private static final Function<Target, Collection<Integer>> EXTRACT_FUNCTION = new Function<SourceObject, Collection<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Collection<Integer> apply(SourceObject o) {
        // extract and return a collection of integers from o
        return Lists.newArrayList(..);
    }
};

Collection<SourceObject> sourceObjects = ...
Collection<Collection<Integer>>> nestedResults = transform(sourceObjects, EXTRACT_FUNCTION);

// Now I have to manually flatten the results by looping and doing addAll over the nestedResults.. 
// Can this be avoided?
Collection<Integer> results = flattenNestedResults(nestedResults);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Guava's `Iterables.concat(Iterable<E>... coll)` to group few iterable results

Comment: This is correct.  Iterables.concat will substitute for your flattenNestedResults function.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is a `reduce` / `fold` method. Currently `Guava` does not support it though there is an open issue: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=218

Maybe it's a better idea that you do not use a `Function`, but iterate it and add to one collection. Guava is a great framework but it cannot do everything.

Comment: I did not know `Iterables.concat(Iterable<E>... coll)`, you can use that if you do not mind the result is an `Iterable` instead of `Collection`

Comment: And there's another similar issue: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=546

Comment: If you really need a collection, you can usually combine `Iterables.concat()` with a copy method such as `Lists.newArrayList()`, `ImmutableList.copyOf()`, `Sets.newHashSet()`, or `ImmutableSet.copyOf()`. Returning an Iterable view is quite clever, since it lets you choose the resulting collection type, instead of choosing one arbitrarily for you. It also avoids copying elements if you don't need a real collection.